# Alternate definition for sup norm

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

My definition for the essential supremum norm as follows. For measurable $f$ defined on a measurable set $E$, the essential supremum norm of $f$ over $E$ is
$$
||f||_{L^{\infty}(E)} = ||f||_{\infty} = \inf \left\{\sup_{x \in A} |f(x)|: A \text{ measurable}, m(E \setminus A) = 0\right\}.
$$

I was reading a proof showing that $||f||_{\infty} = 0 \implies f = 0$ almost everywhere, which used the fact that

$$
||f||_{\infty} = \inf \left\{ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}: m\left\{x: \left|f(x)\right| > \alpha\right\} = 0\right\}.
$$

I am struggling to prove this alternate form of $||f||_{\infty}$ from my definitions of measurable functions, sets, etc. though, and would appreciate some help.

Comment: By your definition, if $\|f\|_{\infty}=0$, then in particular $\sup_{x \in E}|f(x)|=0$ which implies that $f(x)=0$ on $E$

Comment: What have you tried?  The complement of $\{x \, \mid \, |f(x)| > \alpha\}$ is the set $\{x \, \mid \, |f(x)| \leq \alpha\}$, and we know the sup on such a set is at most $\alpha$ so at least one direction of the equality should be clear.

Comment: Related questions, which could probably also serve as duplicates: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549632/properties-of-f-infty-the-infinity-norm) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2272732/alternative-definition-of-f-infty-as-the-smallest-of-all-numbers-of-the).

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer, your answer on the question you linked solved my question. Many thanks, I will mark it as a duplicate accordingly.